# How to get value from reference table based on foreign key?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, relation

I have two tables with the foreign key relating them:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmrSU.jpg)

I have used a SQL query to retrieve the value form both tables:

```
User u = new User();

String sql = "SELECT * FROM user INNER JOIN account ON user.id = account.user WHERE user.id = 1 ";

try {
        Statement stm = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rsu = stm.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rsu.next()){
            u.setFname(rsu.getString("fname"));
            u.setLname(rsu.getString("lname"));
            u.setMname(rsu.getString("mname"));
            u.setGender(rsu.getString("gender"));
            u.setAddress(rsu.getString("address"));
            u.setCitizenship(rsu.getLong("citizenship"));

            /**
            *
            *   Here i want to get values of account table and set it on 
            *   user object to return u
            *
            */
        }

        return u;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: suppose you can directly access the result set values with column names.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the values of table. All you need to do is provide the column name of account table which you already got in your ResultSet.

```
u.setAccountID(rsu.getLong("accId"));
```

Here account id is stored in Result set object which you already retrieved from database in result set

Answer (score 0):

1) Include account data in your SQL like so:

`SELECT user.*, account.* FROM user INNER JOIN account ON user.id = account.user WHERE user.id = 1`

2) Access account field just like user fields:

`u.setAccountType(rsu.getString("accountType"));
u.setAccountNo(rsu.getString("accountNo"));`

3) Make sure to close `Statement` in `finally` block.

4) You dont need to iterate the whole result set since you are expecting only one record. Just replace `while` with `if`.

Comment: didn't work ... it shows error on the line 
    u.setAccountType(rsu.getString("accountType"));

Comment: What is the error. Here I am just guessing that you have `setAccountType` method on `User` object.